# handling merge scenario in user event script in netsuite

Tags: merge, netsuite

I have successfully handled 'create', 'delete' and 'edit' types in afterSubmit event in a User Event script in NetSuite. What I need now is a way to capture Merge events. When I merge two customer records in Netsuite, the function below isn't invoked at all while it's invoked when I create, delete or edit a customer:

```
function afterSubmit(type)
{ 
...
}
```

Is there any way to handle merge scenarios?

Comment: can you please re-phrase it with some example, how you want it to be ?

Comment: Why do you need to handle merges? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to keep track of all the changes made in the customers list in NetSuite and log them externally, including creation of new customer, modification of an existing customer's details. I have created a User Event script in NetSuite that has successfully handled 'new', 'edit' and 'delete' scenarios, but it cannot capture merge so I can't log it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @felipechang's advice, I created a custom Merge Suitelet and all of the logic needed to go with it. All code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jmbeach/01b60e3ad75ce732ca3db1eddcc88794)

## Step 1

Create (or add logic to) the Customer User Event script to hide the existing merge button and add a separate one.

[gist](https://gist.github.com/jmbeach/01b60e3ad75ce732ca3db1eddcc88794#file-userevent_customer-js)

## Step 2

Create (or add logic to) the Cutomer Client script to wire up the merge button click event.

[gist](https://gist.github.com/jmbeach/01b60e3ad75ce732ca3db1eddcc88794#file-client_customer-js)

## Step 3

Create a Merge page Suitelet that mimics the functionality of the out-of-the-box merge page but behaves differently on submit.

[gist](https://gist.github.com/jmbeach/01b60e3ad75ce732ca3db1eddcc88794#file-suitelet_customermergepage-js)

## Step 4

Create a Merge page Client script

[gist](https://gist.github.com/jmbeach/01b60e3ad75ce732ca3db1eddcc88794#file-suitelet_customermergeclientscript-js)

## Step 5

Create a scheduled task that gets launched on Merge submit to check the progress of the merge task and then fire off custom logic if it succeeds

[gist](https://gist.github.com/jmbeach/01b60e3ad75ce732ca3db1eddcc88794#file-scheduledtask_customermerge-js)

Hopefully that saves someone some time.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. This looks like some solid code. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Merge is not an event, it is handled by a duplicate manager.

Unless you hijack the merge button from the client side, I'm not sure it can be done.

Comment: How can I associate a script to the merge button? The merge page doesn't look like a standard NetSuite form where I could assign a client script to the form.

Comment: **Hijacking:** You would replace via jQuery the function run by the merge button with an own client-side function, and then execute the Netsuite natrual process. Check the onclick action for the merge button.  
This is of course not an orthodox way of doing things, and not really recommended, but it gets you where you want to be.  
Also check the nlobjDuplicateJobRequest on the help files if you want to do an own merge button.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to editing netsuite standard scripts, is to **run a scheduled mapReduce on the netsuite record** type in question. Running a search in the mapReduces getInputData, filtering on **["systemnotes.context","anyof","DPL"]** (DPL => Duplicate Resolution) and processing the affected records in the map. Depending how immediately you need the event of the merge dictates the regularity of the scheduling. Unfortunately you cannot get the data of the merging record. If this is needed, I would recommend the business process is put in place to add the desired data to the master record before doing a merge.